# xsl calculation according to distinct values

Tags: xslt, distinct

my xml looks like next:

```
<root>
  <r time="2" user="loginIP=100&amp;loginName=a0" />
  <r time="3" user="loginIP=101&amp;loginName=a2" />
  <r time="4" user="loginIP=102&amp;loginName=a3" />
  <r time="6" user="loginIP=101&amp;loginName=a2" />
  <r time="5" user="loginIP=104&amp;loginName=a5" />
  <r time="8" user="loginIP=105&amp;loginName=a7" />
  <r time="9" user="loginIP=105&amp;loginName=a7" />
  <r time="11" user="loginIP=104&amp;loginName=a5" />
</root>
```

Q: now I want to get total time of each user (loginName stands for the user), then show which user's total time is minimum, and which user's total time is max.

I tried to use: //r[not(substring-after(./@user,"loginName=")=substring-after(following-sibling::r/@user,"loginName="))] to get the all user name first, but it failed, this xpath will return duplicate value.

so how can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

The XSLT 1.0 stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:key name="user" match="root/r" use="substring-after(substring-after(@user, '='), '=')"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="r[generate-id() = generate-id(key('user', substring-after(substring-after(@user, '='), '='))[1])]">
    <xsl:sort select="sum(key('user', substring-after(substring-after(@user, '='), '='))/@time)" data-type="number"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/r">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('User: ', substring-after(substring-after(@user, '='), '='), ': ', sum(key('user', substring-after(substring-after(@user, '='), '='))/@time))"/>
  <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
    <xsl:text> (minimum)</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
    <xsl:text> (maximum)</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

uses Muenchian grouping to group by the user and then sorts by the `sum` of the `@time` values in each group to output the sorted values, indicating the smallest and largest value.

So for your sample the ouput is

```
User: a0: 2 (minimum)
User: a3: 4
User: a2: 9
User: a5: 16
User: a7: 17 (maximum)
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain this expression ' r[generate-id() = generate-id(key('user', substring-after(substring-after(@user, '='), '='))[1])] ' ?

Comment: See http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml for an explanation of Muenchian grouping. The `substring-after(substring-after(@user, '='), '=')` is my attempt to extract the user id from the full attribute value. That is used to define a key. And Muenchian grouping processes the first item in each group, unfortunately a complex expression like `r[generate-id() = generate-id(key('user', substring-after(substring-after(@user, '='), '='))[1])` is needed to do that.